# Qt MainWindow resize/drag event interfering with the background thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a desktop application (for Windows) which has an ordinary `MainWindow` class, with Line Edits and Labels and such. Nothing special going there.

This UI class creates an instance of another class which is derived from QThread, and has two functions:

1- Has a static system call (winapi) function in its .h file, which is connected to a communication device's message receive event (connection happens at api level too)

2- Has an infinite loop (in QThread's `run` method) which processes the messages put to a queue by the interrupt handler.

3- The static message queue used in these two methods is protected by static "`QMutex`" and "`QSemaphore`" variables created within the same class (`message1553`)

MainWindow method that calls the method that starts the thread, again nothing special there either.

```
void MainWindow::on_startTestButton_clicked()
{
    msg1553 = new message1553();
    msg1553->startBC();

}
```

The code which starts the device (and the thread loop):

```
int message1553::startBC()
{
    //some code to initialize and get the device going
    is1553Running = true;
    QThread::start(/*default priority*/);
    return 1;
}
```

This is the interrupt handler (located in message1553.h file) which will be triggered periodically (as a result of some system call from the device when a message is ready):

```
static void __stdcall StatusResponseIRQ(S16BIT DevNum, U32BIT dwIrqStatus)
{
        //...
        if (sMsg.wType == ACE_MSG_RTTOBC)
        {
            mut.lock();
            StatusMessage* gStatusMessage = new StatusMessage;

            statusMessageQueue.enqueue(gStatusMessage);

            sem.release();

            mut.unlock();
        //...
        }
}
```

This is the loop in the `message1553` thread:

```
void message1553::run()
{

    while(is1553Running)
    {

        if(!sem.tryAcquire())
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            mut.lock();
            StatusMessage* stat = statusMessageQueue.dequeue();
            mut.unlock();

            emit invokeStatusMessageControls(stat);
        }
    }
}
```

`message1553` class may receive interrupt requests at any time (actually, it will receive these requests continuously, at a fast pace, namely 1 message in 400 usecs.)

`message1553` thread loop will handle the queue seperately, getting 1 item at a time and sending the message object to `MainWindow` via a signal (in order to update its GUI elements).

Now, I will try to list my findings:

1- Whenever I resize the main window, some of the interrupt messages are missed (I can understand this by monitoring the message numbers located in the message.)

2- No message skipping occurs unless I mingle with the GUI.

3- (Strangest part) I severed all connections between `MainWindow` and `message1553` classes. I commented out the "connect" line, the "emit" line and any declarations. All the relation is severed, save the creation and starting lines of the message1553 class in the MainWindow code. But messages are still skipped if I resize/drag the MainWindow.

4- If I comment out the whole thread loop (inside the `run` method), the problem does not occur. Whatever I do to the main window, the interrupts work just fine.

5- I tried changing the priority of the `message1553` thread, if I raise it too high, the MainWindow becomes unresponsive. If I keep it too low, there are still messages missed.

6- I tried changing the connection type parameter in the `connect` method. Tried `Qt::QueuedConnection`,`Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`, etc. to no avail. The skipping occurs as soon as I begin resizing the main window.

All the problems and the findings lead to one core question: Why does the `MainWindow` event loop and its activities affect a thread working in the back which has no connection with the MainWindow whatsoever (other than running in the same application)?

I would appreciate any info, any perspective or hint, in general or in specific. I have to solve this problem and receive all the messages intact, otherwise my application will have a critical bug in it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why the multiple calls to `sem.tryAcquire()` in `message1553::run`?  If the first succeeds and the second, tested one, fails then the message will be ignored for the time being.  Also, given that this is running on its own thread why use `tryAcquire` at all as you've basically got a busy-waiting loop -- you could use `QSemaphore::acquire` instead.

Comment: That is an editorial fault, let me correct it, thank you.

Comment: About the `tryAcquire` , it is an attempt in keeping the thread unlocked (unblocked). acquire halts the method in that line, which renders it impervious to the changes in `isThreadRunning` flag.

Comment: You might be focused on the wrong thing: please prove to yourself that the process the thread is in does make a difference. Run the I/O in a separate process and see if there are still problems. My experience is that window resizes, on some systems, block everything. Whatever caused it is fixed in Windows 10, but at least in Windows 7 with some video drivers, window resizing can stall all threads on all cores.

Comment: @KubaOber it seems so, resizing action seems to block other threads. And I'm indeed working on Windows 7. But if there were a method to avoid this, I'm all ears.

Comment: "resizing action seems to block other threads" You've just repeated what you already stated in the question. Does it block threads in **other processes** too? If it does, then there's no fix other than abandoning Windows 7. You can't work around that really.

Comment: @KubaOber I'm sorry, I did not read the comment carefully the first time. According to my observations, the resize operation does not affect other **processes**. The problem remains in the thread level, in my original process. Such that, if I do not start the QThread's run method, the interruption goes without problems. That's why I think there may be some kind of solution.